# Is it possible to install OpenGeo within Amazon Web Services - Free Tier?

Tags: web-service, boundless-suite

I like to ask if it is possible to install OpenGeo within an instance of the Amazon Web Services - Free Tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible yes, but the free tier does not provide enough RAM to run everything. You'll at least need to disable GeoWebCache, and you should not expect things to work reliably because the free tier is way below the system requirements for OpenGeo Suite.